# Nullable parameter values in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, nullable

I'm writing an MSBuild task to upgrade a database (full source [here](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/source/browse/trunk/src/octalforty.Wizardby.Ci.MSBuild/UpgradeDatabase.cs)) and encountered an error/by design feature I don't know how to deal with. Basically, if I declare:

```
public int? TargetVersion
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    get { return targetVersion; }
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    set { targetVersion = value; }
}
```

and then attempt to assign a value in an `.msbuild` file:

```
<Target Name="Upgrade">
    <UpgradeDatabase ... TargetVersion="10" />
</Target>
```

MSBuild freaks out and says that

> error MSB4030: "10" is an invalid value for the "TargetVersion" parameter of the "UpgradeDatabase" task. The "TargetVersion" parameter is of type "System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]".

How do I assign a value to a nullable property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSBuild doesn't seem to support nullable values then. A workaround would be to use the nullable property internally, but provide a public non-nullable property. This way, the first assignment to the public property will set the internal value from null to a real value, so you have null in a freshly initialized instance, but MSBuild can happily assign its values.

That is, unless there is some way to trick MSBuild into supporting nullables directly :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you look into the [Required] tag a bit more.  That is how MSBuild handles optional vs required parameters.

Comment: Yes, but it's nice to be able to know whether a value was explicitly assigned or not. For instance, what if you'd assigned a TargetVersion of 0 in the OP's example? The nullable type allow you to differentiate between an unset value and an explicitly set value equal to the default value for the type.